# Is this HTML valid?

Tags: html

Does this code contain anything invalid. I have a form with a table inside. Is that alright?

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <table id="myTab">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="id">User ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="id" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><input type="reset" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <div class="error"></div><div class="correct"></div>
</form>
```

For the result -- http://jsfiddle.net/mBwAh/

Comment: Are you having a problem with this code? What problem exactly?

Comment: No problem at all. I just wanted to find out if there was anything I could do to improve. Or was I correct in putting a table inside a form element.

Comment: If you want to check what you've written is valid, there is always the validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: You don't have to ask real people to validate your markup, it's much quicker to [do it yourself](http://validator.w3.org/). And yes it is, apart from the fact that your very last `<td>` needs a `colspan="2"` because it is the only cell in that row.

Comment: Not only is it fine to put your `<input>`s in a `<table>` (although you shouldn't really use them for layout) it is required to put them in something. Putting `<input>`s directly inside a `<form>` element is no longer considered valid, forms are now **only** allowed to contain block-level elements like `<div>`s and `<table>`s.

Comment: So how do I submit a form if the input elements aren't contained in them?

Comment: @DaveRandom why should I put colspan="2". What does the 2 value mean?

Comment: No, I mean the `<input>`s must be children of the block elements. So what you have done there is fine. As long as they are wrapped in a `<form>` it doesn't matter how far down the document tree they are. Wrap them in 30 `<div>`s if you want, as long as those `<div>`s are wrapped in a form.

Comment: @DaveRandom Okay I get it now thanks. And what about the colspan="2" why 2? Why not 3 or 4?

Comment: Because each of your other table rows has two cells, and the last row only has one, the `colspan="2"` denotes that the one cell should span two columns, so all the rows still cover two columns. To be honest browsers will figure this out for themselves, but in order for your markup to be valid you need the `colspan`. It's always best to include colspan and rowspan so there is no room for ambiguity when the page is being rendered.

Comment: [Read this](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html) to learn about colspan and rowspan.

Comment: Just realised your first row has the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<form>` can contain text and markup (paragraphs, lists, etc.), there are no restrictions listed for what it can contain. Here's the W3C spec which says so:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

As for you're `<table>` usage, it's perfectly valid HTML, in fact the `<table>` element is in the HTML5 spec Here's the W3C Spec for that:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element

You'll want to also add a `colspan` to your `<tr>` which only contains one `<td>`, You should also add a `name` attribute to your `<input>` as it won't do anything on submit without it.

```
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not saying what the problem is, but one thing that catches the eye is the fact that you have differing numbers of `td`s per row without a `colspan` to even them out.

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="2">  <--- makes column span across three columns in the other rows
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <table id="myTab">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label for="id">User ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="id" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="reset" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <div class="error"></div><div class="correct"></div>
</form>
```

Some `colspan`s were missing.

You can check the code for HTML5 validity here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 1):

This might be "Valid", but you're using a table structure for layout purpose, which is not a great idea. If possible, you should change your stucture to something like this.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <label for="id">User ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="id" /><br />
    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" /><br />
    <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button><br />
    <input type="reset" /><br />
    <div class="error"></div><div class="correct"></div>
</form>
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: This is what I had at first before I thought I'd use a table for layout instead lol.

Comment: A good code is not a good code if you didn't rewrite it at least twice :P